# Array.Sort doesn't work correctly in for{} loop

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

So, I'm trying to first make an array consisting of, let's say 5 integers.
Going through the for loop so the user will enter each integer separately.
However, the Array.Sort() function causes the array to be incomplete and it also replaces the last integers in the array.
This happens **only when I try to Sort inside the 'for' loop**, but **sorting outside the loop works**, and I can't tell why. Thanks.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nLive Array Sort\n\n");
Console.Write("Write number of elements to sort: ");
int max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int[] array = new int[max];
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
    int index = i - 1;
    Console.Write($"\nEnter Element [{i}] Index [{index}]: ");
    array[index] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Sorted Array Elements: ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    Array.Sort(array);
    for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
    {
        if (array[j] != 0)
            Console.Write("\t" + array[j]);
    }
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.Write("\n");
}
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("\nSuccessfully completed!");
Console.Read();
```

Comment: What is `SortedArrayy`?

Comment: Sorry, replace it with Array.Sort(array);

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it is correct

Comment: Now it's the right one. Sorry

Comment: Runnable repro: https://dotnetfiddle.net/62DKYj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, of course, is that you're always inserting each new element into `array[index]`. However, the sort operation is re-ordering your array, and `array[index]` isn't always the next unset element!

Let's take an example:

Index: 0
Input number: 1
Array: `[1, 0, 0]`
Sorted array: `[0, 0, 1]`

Index: 1
Input number: 2
Array: `[0, 2, 1]`
Sorted array: `[0, 1, 2]`

Index: 2
Input number: 3
Array: `[0, 2, 3]`
Sorted array: `[0, 2, 3]`

See what happened on that last iteration? The sort operation on the previous iteration left the array containing `[0, 1, 2]` in that (sorted) order, but our logic said that we needed to insert the new element at index 2, which overwrite the last element in the array (giving `[0, 1, 3]`)!

The key to debugging these sorts of problems is to work through your code step-by-step. Preferably in a debugger, as this lets you look at all of your variables in each loop iteration, but you can also do it by printing out the contents of your variables and then inspecting them.

---

One solution is not to sort your array until after your loop, as you found.

Another it to use a list, rather than an array. A list lets you add elements one-by-one, so you never have a situation where you're trying to sort a collection which contains some elements which have been correctly set, and some which are still waiting to be set.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nLive Array Sort\n\n");
Console.Write("Write number of elements to sort: ");
int max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
List<int> list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
{
    int index = i - 1;
    Console.Write($"\nEnter Element [{i}] Index [{index}]: ");
    list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
    Console.Write("Sorted List Elements: ");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
    list.Sort();
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {
        Console.Write("\t" + list[j]);
    }
    Console.ResetColor();
    Console.Write("\n");
}
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("\nSuccessfully completed!");
Console.Read();
```

Notice how this also let us get rid of the `if (array[j] != 0)` check, since our list only contains elements which we've added so far.

Comment: The fix would be to sort the array after the for loop or to use a list.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes I think I just edited in the list example before you edited your comment to suggest it, but it's a close-run thing!

Comment: Thanks for the list suggestion, I'll definitely go for that.

Comment: However, still wanna understand something. So I won't sort `array` in the for loop, but I made a new array instead calling it `newarray` and gave it the same value as my old array so I can sort it in the for loop without having issues, since it'll be used just once anyway without touching the original array, but it's still the same issue.

Comment: @Luffy I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to describe in your comment. Perhaps ask a new question, with a proper code sample? If this answer solved the question at the top of the page, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/HJSGqf Here's what I'm trying to explain, there I'm using a brand new array to sort it and I'd just ditch it anyway after used once, so I thought it might work that way, but I don't get this case

Comment: An array is a reference type, so you are not making a copy of the array. `int[] sortedarray = array;`. Both variables now point to the same array!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes would a `SortedList<TKey,TValue>` be useful in this case?

Comment: @zaggler From the description of that class: "Represents a collection of key/value pairs". OP doesn't have key/value pairs. You *could* make it work, but sorting a tiny list is so trivially cheap it's almost certainly not worth it

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes how can I make a clone/copy array in that case? So that any actions would be done only for that clone.

Comment: `int[] sortedarray = new int[array.Length];` `sortedarray = array;` `Array.Sort(sortedarray);` that seems to also be reference (although I don't know why)

Comment: Yes, it would. However, a sorted list is a keyed collection, I think. Better use a `List<int>`. where you can add new items with `list.Add(i)`. New elements are added at the end of the list without you having to specify an index. This lets you sort the list inside the loop with no undesired side effects. See @canton7's code example. The reference to the new `sortedarray` will just be replaced by a reference to `array` and the new array will be lost. You must use `Array.Copy`, to copy an array.

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of the `Array.Copy` method. I'll definitely give it a try to see how it works and just use a `List<int>` anyway. Thanks both!